# DTFT of a triangle function in closed form

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am sampling a continuous signal $x_c(t)$ that follows a [triangle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_function) in the time domain, meaning:

$$x_c(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}1-|t/a|,&|t|<|a|\\ 0,&\mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Parameter $a$ is an integer multiple of my sampling interval $T_0$ such that $a=kT_0$.  Thus:

$$x_d[n]=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}1-|n/k|,&|n|<|k|\\ 0,&\mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

I am wondering if a [discrete-time Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) $x_d[n]$ exists in closed-form, like the continuous-time Fourier transform of $x_c(t)$.  I know that the continuous time triangle function is the convolution of two [rectangular functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function), and I know that the discrete-time Fourier transform exists in closed form for the rectangular function, however, I am having trouble writing down my sampled discrete version of the triangle function as a convolution of two discrete rectangles.

It is interesting that the *inverse* DTFT for the triangle function (i.e. triangle function in the frequency domain) is listed in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Table_of_discrete-time_Fourier_transforms) and it looks very much like the Fourier transform of the continuous-time version.  If the other side of the DTFT doesn't exist (in closed form), I'd be interested in learning the reason why, as I am new to the signal processing and Fourier analysis world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have to compute
$$X(\omega):=\sum_{n\in{\mathbb Z}}\ x(n)e^{-i\omega n}$$
for the function $$x(n):=\Bigl(1-{|n|\over N}\Bigr)\qquad (|n|<N)$$ and $x(n):=0$ otherwise. It follows that
$$X(\omega)=1 +\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \Bigl(1-{n\over N}\Bigr) (e^{i\omega n}+ e^{-i\omega n})=1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \Bigl(1-{n\over N}\Bigr) \cos(n\omega)\ .$$
Mathematica can compute this sum; we get
$$X(\omega)={\sin^2(N\omega/2) \over N \sin^2(\omega/2)}\ .$$
Basis of this result is the formula for the sum of the finite geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}  z^n$ and a similar formula for sums of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n z^n$.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know it was this simple -- and the formula looks very similar to the continuous version.

Answer (score 6):

The convolution-based approach: define $y_d[n]=1$ if $0\le n<k$, and $y_d[n]=0$ otherwise. Then 
$$x_d[n] = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{m} y_d[m]y_d[m-n]\tag{1}$$
which is the convolution of $y_d$ with its reflection $\tilde y_d[n]=y_d[-n]$. The Fourier transform of $y_d$ is easy to find:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} e^{-i\omega n} = \frac{1-e^{-i\omega k}}{1-e^{-i\omega }} = \frac{e^{ i\omega k/2 }-e^{-i\omega k/2}}{e^{ i\omega/2 }-e^{-i\omega/2 }}e^{-i\omega(k-1)/2}  = \frac{\sin(k\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)} e^{-i\omega(k-1)/2}
$$ 
The transform of reflection $\tilde y_d[n]$ is the conjugate of the above, so the only difference is the exponential term becoming $e^{i\omega(k-1)/2}$. When the transforms are multiplied, the exponential cancels out, and the result is 
$$\frac{\sin^2(k\omega/2)}{\sin^2(\omega/2)} $$ Recall the factor of $1/k$ in $(1)$, and that's it.

Comment: This is a very nice answer -- I love the use of the fact that triangle function is a convolution of two rectangular functions.  I feel it makes this a very intuitive solution.